# How do I populate an editable form field with logged in user name in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create an e-commerce application using django. The customer logs in and when placing an order he/she has to fill a form which has fields like name, phone number, date etc. Since the user has already logged in how to I pre-populate the name field with username and how do i make the field editable so that if the user wants to change the username to something else.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your answer to include the code from `views.py` and possibly `forms.py`!

Answer (score 1):

If your order form is created with Django templates you can pre-populate form field values from template context. Something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="first-name" name="first_name" value="{{ request.user.first_name }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you share what you've already tried to build yourself, I can only point you to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values).

If you are using django-forms as is, it's pretty easy.

Basically what you'll want to do is create the Form object with initial values, something like this:

`form = Form(initial={'username': user.user_name})`

This will fill in the given for this particular field.